# Get absolute path of a relative path of a XML file

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

Is it possible to guess the absolute path of a relative path that I have specified for loading a XML file?  This is my coding:

```
$strXML = __DIR__ . "/../xml/file.xml";
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($strXML);

$strPath = fullPathFunction($xmlFile);  //Desired function
```

Comment: Why guess when you can use [`realpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.realpath.php)?

Comment: @Phil I'm already using realpath() function, but when I use it, I'm just geting `/home/user/public_html` but my expected result is `/home/user/public_html/xml/file.xml`

Comment: Try `$strXML = __DIR__ . '/../xml/file.xml';` assuming the path is relative to your `.php` script

Comment: @Phil I think we are near.  `__DIR__` is geting the path to my `.php` file, so it gets `/home/user/public_html/php` but my `.xml` file is inside `/home/user/public_html/xml` directory

Comment: Yes, I realise that. That is why the path `/../xml/file.xml` is appended to `__DIR__`. If `__DIR__` is `/home/user/public_html/php`, then `/home/user/public_html/php/../xml/file.xml` will resolve (via `realpath()`) to `/home/user/public_html/xml/file.xml`. If you're now using `__DIR__`, please update the code in your question

Comment: You've copied my code incorrectly. Note that the string path starts with `/` and not `..` ~ `$strXML = __DIR__ . '/../xml/file.xml';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `realpath` function:

```
$strXML = "../xml/file.xml";
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($strXML);

$strPath = realpath($strXML);
```

[image: This example works for me]

Comment: I'm already using realpath() function, but when I use it, I'm just geting `/home/user/public_html` but my expected result is `/home/user/public_html/xml/file.xml`

Comment: That's not sense. `realpath` would return the folder that contains the file, in this case `/home/user/public_html/xml`, please, print the var_dump of $file are used as argument in `realpath` function.

Comment: update: added the filename to complete the expected result.

Comment: The result is `string(15) "../xml/file.xml"`

Comment: please, check the screen i was posted, it's working for me :S

Comment: As I have answered to @Phil, it seems to be a problem about file locations.  My `.php` file is inside `/home/user/public_html/php` and my `.xml` file is inside `/home/user/public_html/xml`

Comment: You should ideally prefix the relative path with `__DIR__` (see comments on question above) to avoid issues with PHP's _include path_

Comment: @Phil it's not necessary, if the php code find the xml file, then realpath too.

Comment: @Alberto If you see my screen, my php is inside `/var/www/html` and my xml is in `/var/www/xml`, and works fine. Try to check with an empty php with my code.

Comment: @Oscargeek try running the script from a file in a different directory that includes the above `.php` file. It won't work because the CWD will be different. That's why it's always beneficial to prefix relative paths

Comment: This it what I get when I make it with an empty `.php`  http://res.cloudinary.com/saintseiya/image/upload/v1536558226/1_tha1ge.jpg

Comment: try `$strPath = realpath($strXML);` not `$strPath = realpath($xmlFile);`. Please, see my example :)

Comment: @Phil see my example, i did it. Relative paths works, in another way he could not load the xml either. If you prefear an absolute path, well, but it's the same.

Comment: Same result  :(  http://res.cloudinary.com/saintseiya/image/upload/v1536558900/2_nfkyhj.jpg

Comment: Volví a escribir mal los caracteres.  Gracias por tu paciencia, Oscar  :)  Ahora sí me ha salido  :)  http://res.cloudinary.com/saintseiya/image/upload/v1536559870/3_td4dnb.jpg

Comment: Don't problem, glad to help ;)